# String tokenizer in vb.net? How to split multiple symbol multiple variant?

Tags: regex, vb.net, split

This is just pure own hobby to do at free time.
So I saw excel formula is quite annoying and hard to read. So I think why don't they format it?
So I decided to fry it turn out it's really hard, I managed to format up until this complexity:
`IF((2+5) > 6, more, less)`

then initially I process it like this

```
IF
(
(
2 + 5
)
>
6
,
more
,
less
)
```

Then I transform it becomes

```
IF (2+5) > 6 THEN
    more
ELSE
    LESS
END IF
```

Yea I think you got the idea. So this will increase the difficulty, I still managed to solve it 
 `IF((2+5) > 6, more, IF(3<6, less, duh))`
Desire output:

```
IF 3 < 6 THEN
    less
ELSE
    duh
END IF

IF (2+5) > 6 THEN
    more
ELSE
    result
END IF
```

Want a harder one? mixed arithmetic with bracket inside, here is the sample, try it. I didn't manage to solve it yet, so I post here see who can complete this challenge: 
`IF(I28<F$30,IF(H28>=F$29,(F$30-I28)*F$32,(F$30-I28)*F$33),0)` expected output:

```
IF (H28>=F$29) THEN
    (F$30-I28)*F$32
ELSE
    (F$30-I28)*F$33
END IF

IF (I28<F$30) THEN
    result
ELSE
    0
END IF
```

For me the difficult part of this is there is a bracket inside. To separate it out is not as easy as it look. Please share with me your approach if you manage to solve it, I will post another complex equation involve other pattern if you want to try

Answer (score -1):

You state that:

```
IF((2+5) > 6, more, IF(3<6, less, duh))
```

Should produce:

```
IF 3 < 6 THEN
    less
ELSE
    duh
END IF

IF (2+5) > 6 THEN
    more
ELSE
    result
END IF
```

But that is two separate `If...Else` blocks, which are NOT equivalent to the original Excel statement.

The correct output for your original `If()` statement would be a NESTED `If...Else` statement:

```
IF (2+5) > 6 THEN
    more
ELSE
    IF 3 < 6 THEN
        less
    ELSE
        duh
    END IF
END IF
```

Note that we never get to "less" or "duh" if the first condition is met.  This is not the case with your output.

Comment: I know, but convert to nested-if is more difficult isn't it? But if you could parse it into nested-if I salute for the skill though